# bash floating math using python

Tags: python, bash

I am using `python -c` in bash to do some floating math tests. It appears I am missing something as it's giving me a syntax error.

```
#!/bin/bash
num1=1.2
num2=3.4
num3=1.5
num4=1.5
volfree=10
TAdd=$(python -c "print $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4")

if (( $(( num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 )) == 0 )) ; then
               echo "Sum is equal to 0"
elif (( $(python -c "print $TAdd >  $volfree") )); then
                echo "(( $( python -c "print $TAdd - $volfree"))) is your final number";
else
    echo "something needs to be done"
fi
```

Error output:

```
[user@linuxmachine ~]# bash -x testsize.sh
+ num1=1.2
+ num2=3.4
+ num3=1.5
+ num4=1.5
+ volfree=10
++ python -c 'print 1.2 + 3.4 + 1.5 + 1.5'
+ TAdd=7.6
testsize.sh: line 9: 1.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2")
[user@linuxmachine ~]#
```

My Python version is Python 2.7.5

Comment: Which version of python are you using? If you're using Python 3.x you need to know that the print statement now needs parantheses. Ie. your print calls should be ```print("hello world")```

Comment: Also, bash doesn't have floating types. You should instead use a program like ```bc``` to do the calculations

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do floating math in bash so I am inclined to use python -c as its much easier and rhel7 comes installed with it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/hwrnmQumtPw?t=790

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite this as follows:

```
num1=1.2
num2=3.4
num3=1.5
num4=1.5
volfree=10

# Avoid dynamic code generation; pass values as command-line arguments.
# Compute the diff between the sum and volfree now, rather than waiting to compare them
diff=$(python -c 'from sys import argv; print sum(map(float, argv[1:5])) - argv[5]' "$num1" "$num2" "$num3" "$num4" "$volfree")

# We already know bash doesn't do floating-point arithmetic; don't bother
# checking if num1 + ... + num4 == 0 in shell.
# not (...) maps 0/False to an exit status of 1, and 1/True to 0
if python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(not (float(sys.argv[1] > 0)))' "$diff"; then
    echo "$diff is your final number"
else
    echo "something needs to be done"
fi
```

That said, such one-liners really aren't a strong point of Python. Use `awk` instead.

```
diff=$(echo "$num1 $num2 $num3 $num4 $volfree" | awk '{print $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 - $5}')
if echo "$diff" | awk '{exit(!($1 > 0))}'; then
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

I've changed your first if statement to use `bc` to do the floating point arithmetic, and changed the parentheses in the bash if statement to use `[[ ]]` instead of `(( ))`. I'm not really sure why you're doing some arithmetic in bash and some in python though.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
num1=1.2
num2=3.4
num3=1.5
num4=1.5
volfree=10
TAdd=$(python -c "print $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4")

if [[ `echo $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4 | bc` == 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Sum is equal to 0"
elif (( $(python -c "print $TAdd >  $volfree" ))); then
    echo "(( $( python -c "print $TAdd - $volfree "))) is your final number";
else
    echo "something needs to be done"
fi
```

### Avoiding `bc`

Although I echo the sentiment of @CharlesDuffy's comments below, if you *really* don't want to use `bc`, you can replace the first if statement above with `if [[ $(python -c "print($num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4)") == 0 ]]`.

### Edit

I'll admit that I didn't focus much attention on your overall goal, and instead focused on fixing your syntax errors. Though my implementation fixes your syntax errors, I'd recommend @chepner's more considered solution.

Comment: @user63858, ...avoid bc why? It's a lot smaller than the Python interpreter -- quicker to load, fewer dependencies, less content to be loaded into the block cache.

Comment: If you really want to avoid bc you can change your first if statement to ```if [[ $(python -c "print $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4") == 0 ]] ```. But I echo @CharlesDuffy's sentiments about the need to avoid bc

Comment: ...also, because `bc` is a more restricted language, surprising values can do less harm. If `num4='__import__("shutil").rmtree("/etc")'`, you could have a bad day when substituting values to generate Python code.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  I will try them all to see which one fits my needs the most and then come back and update it.

Comment: I had bc initially in my code but if it's not there then the script will fail so it requires additional code to check for it if not then yum install bc -y.  I tried it but it was giving some kind of syntax error while it installs it.

Answer (score 0):

Originally bash do not support floating numbers. To handle floating arithmetic you can use *bc*.
I'm not sure you prefer python or bash, you can assign floating values to a variable with both:

```
TAdd=$(python -c "print $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4")
```

or

```
TAdd=`echo $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4 | bc -l`
```

To compare the variables you can use this code:

```
if (( $echo "TAdd == 0" | bc -l) ));then
```

Your code could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
num1=1.2
num2=3.4
num3=1.5
num4=1.5
volfree=10
TAdd=$(python -c "print $num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4")

if (( $echo "$TAdd == 0" | bc -l) )); then
  echo "Sum is equal to 0"
elif (( $(echo "$TAdd > $volfree" | bc -l) )); then
  diff=`echo "$TAdd - $volfree" | bc -l`
  echo $diff "is your final number"
else
  echo "something needs to be done"
fi
```